How can I access a plugin of a Gradle version catalogue in my settings.gradle.kts?
In my Gradle build (Kotlin) I'm using Micronaut's platform catalog to declare dependencies as static code as listed below.

// I use this way
implementation(mn.micronaut.serde.jackson)

// instead of that§
implementation("io.micronaut.serde:micronaut-serde-jackson")

Since the Micronaut's platform catalog needs to be declared in the settings.gradle.kts
plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.platform.catalog") version "4.3.5"
}

As you probably noticed I have to hard code the Gradle plugin version number 4.3.5 in my settings.gradle.kts but I'd rather like to use the Micronaut version from my gradle/libs.versions.toml file.
[versions]
micronaut = "4.3.7"
micronautGradlePluginVersion = "4.3.5"

[plugins]
micronaut-application = { id = "io.micronaut.application", version.ref = "micronautGradlePluginVersion" }
micronaut-platform = { id = "io.micronaut.platform.catalog", version.ref = "micronautGradlePluginVersion" }

Unfortunately it seems that within the settings.gradle.kts I don't have access to the as I have in a build.gradle.kts file
// build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.micronaut.platform)
}

Is there a way how I can make this working in my settings.gradle.kts without having to hard code the version number or even use something equivalent to
// settings.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.micronaut.platform)
}

?

Unfortunately, this is not possible, as mentioned by a Gradle member in this GitHub issue regarding using version catalog accessors in a settings script:

Version catalogs can't be used before they have been evaluated, which happens during settings evaluation, which is AFTER evaluating settings plugins. So basically a chicken and egg problem; nothing we can do about it.
~ (Make version catalogs available in settings script's plugin block)

Which means that you'll have to manually declare the plugin versions like you're currently doing:
plugins {
    id("io.micronaut.platform.catalog") version "4.3.5"
}


I mean Gradle could just parse the file and offer a consistent API in build.gradle.kts and settings.gradle.kts, but I guess they've decided against it, because this would be too user-friendly

As @Edric says, you can't access the version catalog from settings.gradle.kts.
However, to keep your declarations DRY, you can use a combination of the gradle.properties file and a code-based definition of the version catalog so that you don't have to re-declare the same value.
The pieces of this are:
// gradle.properties

micronautGradlePluginVersion=4.3.5

// settings.gradle.kts

plugins {
    val micronautGradlePluginVersion by settings
    id("io.micronaut.platform.catalog") version micronautGradlePluginVersion
}

val micronautGradlePluginVersion by settings // declaration in plugins block is separate
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    versionCatalogs {
        create("libs") {
            version("micronautGradlePluginVersion", micronautGradlePluginVersion)
        }
    }
}

You could continue to write the whole TOML file in code in the settings file, or you can use the version from above in the TOML file:
// gradle/libs.versions.toml

[plugins]
micronaut-application = { id = "io.micronaut.application", version.ref = "micronautGradlePluginVersion" }
micronaut-platform = { id = "io.micronaut.platform.catalog", version.ref = "micronautGradlePluginVersion" }

